# C++ iterator reference non-exist value

Tags: c++, list, iterator, dereference, multiset

I want to create two iterator `p1` & `p2` to keep pointing to certain elements in a multiset(or list), but weird thing is `*p1 *p2` return a value NOT even in the multiset/list. And in for-loop traversal, `*it` behaves normally.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class MedianFinder
{

private:
    multiset<int> orderedNums;
    int size;
    multiset<int>::iterator p1, p2;

public:
    MedianFinder() : size(0)
    {
        p1 = p2 = orderedNums.begin();
    }

    void addNum(int num)
    {
        orderedNums.insert(num);
        size++;

        cout << "p1: " << *p1 << " p2: " << *p2 << endl;

        cout << "ordered: ";
        for (multiset<int>::iterator it = orderedNums.begin(); it != orderedNums.end(); it++)
        {
            cout << *it << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MedianFinder medianFinder;
    medianFinder.addNum(5); 
    medianFinder.addNum(7); 
    medianFinder.addNum(9); 
    return 0;
}
```

console output:

```
p1: 1 p2: 1
ordered: 5 
p1: 2 p2: 2
ordered: 5 7 
p1: 3 p2: 3
ordered: 5 7 9
```

both list and multiset behave the same...

Comment: dereferencing invalidated iterators or iterators to `end()` has undefined behaviour, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: What happens if you initialize your pointer inside addNum() after you've inserted the first element?  void addNum(int num)
{
    orderedNums.insert(num);
    size++;

    p1 = p2 = orderedNums.begin();   ...

Comment: `insert` does not invalidate iterators, that's fine. The problem is that `begin()` on an empty multiset returns the same thing as `end()`. And the `p` iterators continue to point to the end placeholder and dereferencing that is UB.

Comment: Thanks, so the output `1 2 3` is undefined behavior？To sum up, `insert` would insert elements before `end()`, which p1 and p2 keep pointing at. That leads to undefined behaviour when deferencing p1 and p2. And re-assign `p1 = p2 = orderedNums.begin()` in `addNums()` do solve the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here

> ```
> p1 = p2 = orderedNums.begin();
> ```

you make `p1` and `p2` equal to `orderedNums.end()`, because for an empty container `end == begin`. Dereferencing the end iterator is undefined.

`std::multiset::insert` does not invalidate iterators, but that does not change the fact that `p1` and `p2` refer to the `end` of the container. They do not automagically get updated to refer to the newly inserted element.

Your code has undefined behavior.

Not sure what the actual aim of the code is. If you want to keep an iterator to the last element that was inserted you can store the iterator returned from `std::multiset::insert`.